# will HTML <body> onLoad events overwrite javascript window onload event?

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a HTML page and a javascript function is attached to the `<body>` onLoad event.

I wanted to show up a message dialog when the page loads. I cannot edit the javascript function attached to this onLoad event due to some reasons.

So I created a new javascript file with a single function which will show the message dialog. Then I added this line in my javascript file

```
window.onload = onPageLoad;
```

`onPageLoad()` is my function which could show the message dialog.

I attached this javascript file in my HTML using script tag. When I run this HTML file, `onPageLoad()` function is not getting called.

I want to know whether `<body>` tag, onLoad event overrides the window onload. If so, can someone help me in implementing this functionality somehow.

Please keep in mind that I could not edit my HTML file and I could write only new javascript file. Thanks.

Comment: can you attach some codes? try use `domready` instead

Comment: Can you add the code to the body?, i.e. at the bottom of the page? Also what is the code you are calling in the body onload. You may be able to replace the function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on browser. window.onload currently overwrites body onload in Chrome, Firefox and Safari on OSX

You can ADD your function to the onload:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  alert('window.onload')
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert('addEventListener')
  }, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE < 9
  window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
    alert('attachEvent')
  });
}
```

```html
<body onload="alert('body onload')">

</body>
```

AND/OR Replace

```js
var bodyOnload = document.body.onload;
window.onload = function() {
  alert('window.onload')
  bodyOnload()
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    alert('addEventListener')
  }, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) { // IE < 9
  window.attachEvent('onload', function() {
    alert('attachEvent')
  });
}
```

```html
<body onload="alert('body onload')">

</body>
```

Comment: Are you able to think of any way to implement what I want? If so let me know. Thanks.