# body onload function is not working in my Example (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am writing a program to find sequence of execution of **document.ready, window.onload, body.onload**, but due to some reason my body.onload is not giving out console.log. Why?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('document is ready now ...');
});

window.onload = () => {
    console.log('window is loaded...');
}

function bodyOnload() {
    console.log('body is loaded...');
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="bodyOnload()">

<h1>Hello ...</h1>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [will HTML <body> onLoad events overwrite javascript window onload event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194676/will-html-body-onload-events-overwrite-javascript-window-onload-event)

Comment: yeah, I think this link is just the correct answer.

Comment: The correct answer is more complex. When you attach a load listener to `body` with `addEventListener` inside `body`, it's never run. `DOMContentLoaded` listeners are always fired first, in the order of attaching, then a `window.load` listener set in `head`, then `body.onload` set in the tag, and finally `window.load` set at the end of the `body`. Events fire in this order in Firefox 82, but the order is possibly messed up if adding `defer/async` attributes to the scripts. Notice, that this must be tested on a simple page, you can't use a framework or a script host like JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3):

I'm gonna tell you the reason with some example cases...
[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('document is ready now ...');
    });

    window.onload = () => {
        console.log('window is loaded...');
    }

    function bodyOnload() {
        console.log('body is loaded...');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyOnload()">
<h1>Hello ...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see window.onload doesn't work in the above case.
But in the below case, you can see that body.onload doesn't work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyOnload()">
<h1>Hello ...</h1>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('document is ready now ...');
    });

    window.onload = () => {
        console.log('window is loaded...');
    }

    function bodyOnload() {
        console.log('body is loaded...');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

So even if you write the separately it won't wok.
Overall, those can't be working together.
Why?
window.onload means the body is already loaded and body.onload also means the window is already loaded.
since the reason, in case one of both is called the other one will be ignored.